# What's the difference between VisualViewport.offsetTop and VisualViewport.pageTop?

Tags: css, viewport, cssom

Spec's here, https://wicg.github.io/visual-viewport/, but I can't understand the difference.

Aren't the "initial containing block origin" coordinates always the same as the layout viewport coordinates?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I bookmarked this post to take a look at it later if no one answers it, and here I am. I've just tested this API, and I can say that without zooming in **VisualViewport.pageTop** acts the same way as `pageYOffset`:
[image: VisualViewport.pageTop]

---

Next, **VisualViewport.offsetTop** remains 0 til you zoom in, and if you do it shows offset  (made this example on my mobile device so it's more noticeable):
[image: VisualViewport.offsetTop]

---

If you zoom in pageYOffset and VisualViewport.pageTop will be different and the difference equal to offset `VisualViewport.offsetTop` (here 2974 - 2869 = 105):
[image: pageYOffset and VisualViewport.pageTop when user zooms in]

Resources about visual and layout viewports and other related things:

- [Web Viewports Explainer](https://github.com/bokand/bokand.github.io/blob/master/web_viewports_explainer.md)
- [A tale of two viewports — part one](https://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html)
- [A tale of two viewports — part two](https://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html)